# c# passing class argument to constructor

Tags: c#, object, constructor

The following codes works as is, but I would like to use a reference to the MyProperty class to be passed in the constructor 
instead of the strongly typed references in the inline code.

How do I do this, I expected to pass a ref to MyProperty but everything I have tried fails

I would like PropertyClass to be able to handle any MyProperty classes i.e. no references to MyProperty in PropertyClass

Still learning so sorry if I have missed the obvious !

Many Thanks for any help

Sarah

```
PropertyClass pc = new PropertyClass(!here!);   // Would like to pass MyProperty class here

pc.Settings.Add(new MyProperty("Fred", "Monday"));
pc.SaveXml("MyTest.xml");




public class MyProperty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MyPropName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string MyPropData { get; set; }

    // default constructor needs to be parameterless for serialisation.
    public MyProperty()
    {
    }

    public MyProperty(string Name, string Data)
    {
        MyPropName = Name;
        MyPropData = Data;
    }
}



public class PropertyClass
{
    public List<MyProperty> Settings { get; set; }

    public PropertyClass()              // How to pass the required class here ?
    {                                   // public PropertyClass( ref MyProperty myprop)
        Settings = new List<MyProperty>();
    }

    public void SaveXml(string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyProperty>), new XmlRootAttribute("Settings"));

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            XML.Serialize(stream, Settings, namespaces);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass only the type of object that you want to store in the instance of `PropertyClass`? Have you tried using generics? Or is the question about the serialization's issues with generics?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)?...

Comment: Hi Many Thanks for the reply - I was hoping to have a sealed class that can handle any 'MyProperty' style class that is passed to it. the MyProperty class could consist of any number of objects and serialization of the supplied class is a core part. In short I just don't want to have a PropertyClass for all MyProperty requirements, also I need to fully understand why what I am trying to do does not work !!!

Comment: The answer that I posted seems to serialize correctly according to the attributes that `MyProperty` has, and should be able to handle any class that is serializable.

Comment: To all that have added constructive comments I thank you, to some that just have edited my text to remove any last trait's of human comments I wonder on which planet you do, or would like to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the definition of `PropertyClass` to

```
public class PropertyClass<T>
{
    public List<T> Settings { get; set; }

    public PropertyClass()
    {
        Settings = new List<T>();
    }

    public void SaveXml(string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("Settings"));

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            XML.Serialize(stream, Settings, namespaces);
        }
    }
}
```

The [type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) `T` specifies the type of the items in the `List<T>`, so that you can instantiate `PropertyClass` as follows

```
var pc = new PropertyClass<MyProperty>();
```

Or when you get tired of `MyProperty` you can change it to `new PropertyClass<foo>()` without changing it elsewhere.

Another nice feature that I like about generics is that you can actually place constraints on the type parameter in the line where you declare it like:

```
public class PropertyClass<T> where T : MyClass, IMyInterface, new()
```

This means that `T` has to be derived from `MyClass`, it has to implement `IMyInterface` and has to have a parameterless constructor. (Obviously you do not need to add all such constraints, but they can all be useful in certain cases).

I want to rant a little more, but I am sure you can play with it and find some uses for it.

Comment: Wow Thanks that's fast, I need a little time to absorb what you have said, but I think I understand what you have said ( surprised myself!), I really don't like to do something I don't understand and I like to do neat code that's understandable 5 years down the line. By the way I am moving from Forth to C# so no mean feat. Thanks for the help really appreciated.

Comment: Namelesss One Thanks generics achieves exactly what I needed, I have marked your answer as  accepted. Many Thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a generic class.

```
public class PropertyClass<T>
{
  public List<T> Settings { get; set; }

  public PropertyClass()
  {
    Settings = new List<T>();
  }
...
}

PropertyClass<MyProperty> pc = new PropertyClass<MyProperty>();
```

I must add that your naming is very unclear. `PropertyClass` should be called something like `XmlableList`. And `MyProperty` already exists and is called  `NameValuePair<string,string>`

Comment: Sorry about the naming I was trying to make what I was doing simple, obviously failed, but I have listened to what you have said. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are looking for generics:

```
public class PropertyClass<TMyProperty>
{
    public List<TMyProperty> Settings { get; set; }

    public PropertyClass()
    {                                   
        Settings = new List<TMyProperty>();
    }
    ..
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Work on your naming, it wasn't immediately obvious that PropertyClass was actually a collection of properties; perhaps MyPropertyCollection would be better?

What you're looking for is called constructor overloading. Basically you specify the constructor again, but this time with parameters:

```
public MyPropertyCollection()
{
    Settings = new List<MyProperty>();
}
public MyPropertyCollection(IEnumerable<MyProperty> collection)
{
    Settings = new List<MyProperty>(collection);
}
```

Or to allow `var col = new MyPropertyCollection(new MyProperty(), new MyProperty(), new MyProperty())` you can do:

```
public MyPropertyCollection(params MyProperty[] collection)
{
    Settings = new List<MyProperty>(collection);
}
```

Though you should be careful with that, it doesn't feel right and should you later want to introduce additional parameters, well it could end bad.

Also, as you're basically wrapping a list, what you could also consider is the `System.Collection.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` class as a base:

```
// The Collection<MyProperty> base class is responsible for maintaining the list
public class MyPropertyCollection : Collection<MyProperty>
{
    public MyPropertyCollection()
    {
        // Default base() constructor is called automatically
    }

    public MyPropertyCollection(IList<MyProperty> properties)
        : base(properties)
    {
         // Overloaded constructor calls base constructor with collection of properties
    }

    public void SaveXml(string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Serializer should now target this very class
            var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (this), new XmlRootAttribute("Settings"));

            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            xml.Serialize(stream, this, namespaces);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry It was called MypropCollection but as I was not using collections I changed its name to ask the question. I sincerely thank you for your reply and now need to digest what you have said, I need to understand why and what I am doing and as you can guess this is a small part of a much larger project, previous coding has all been in forth so all this is somewhat different. Appreciated Sarah

Answer (score 0):

this is how you call the constructor

```
PropertyClass pc = new PropertyClass(new MyProperty("Fred", "Monday"));
```

this is the constructor

```
Public MyProperty MyProperty { get; set; }
public PropertyClass(MyProperty _myProperty) 
{
    MyProperty  = _myProperty 
}
```

Comment: You should improve the quality of this answer by adding explanatory details. SO frowns on code-only answers.

Comment: @WilliamCustode it is code to just plug into the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor that takes a `MyProperty` as an argument:

```
public PropertyClass(MyProperty myprop)             
{                                   
    Settings = new List<MyProperty> {myprop};
}
```

Note that `MyProperty` is a reference type so `ref` is unnecessary here (it already *is* a reference).

Comment: I have tried this but how dose the serialization of the passed class pick up its reference. I feel I am missing some important concept here. I need the class to be self contained in being able to handle many differing 'MyProperty' classes which will have different configurations. So if I use the above how does the serialize class use the above concept?